# No access to GraphQL in my docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, dockerfile

I am trying to connect to my GraphQL API in a docker container, but I am not able to reach it in Postman nor a web browser.

[image: My GraphQL API container]

My dockerfile and docker compose file might have a problem, but I am not sure what is broken.

In my docker image file I am exposing ports:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
```

And in my docker-compose file (network is included due to another container):

```
version: '2'
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
services:
  app:
    image: graphql
    volumes:
       - ../:/https/
    env_file: 
       - ../env.secrets
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"
    networks:
      - default
```

```
My appsettings.json file:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Urls": "http://*;https://*"
}
```

If I run my app outside docker and use postman I can access my GraphQL endpoint without any problems and do my queries:
'http://localhost:5000/graphql'

However that is not the case when I run it inside a container. I am sure my ports are configured correctly.

If I run docker container ls I see the following, which looks right:
[image: Docker container list]

Comment: I found this page with someone having the same issue:
https://forums.docker.com/t/using-localhost-to-access-running-container/43998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in Postman. I changed my ports accordingly:

5000-5001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->80/tcp

So my port mapping in my compose file is changed to:

```
services:
  app5:
    image: graphql-app5-demo
    volumes:
       - ../:/https/
    env_file: 
       - ../env.secrets
    ports:
       - 5000:80
    networks:
      - default
```

And my postman endpoind URL:
"http://localhost:5000/graphql"

Although I really wants to not use port 80 here, but rather use the same port as 5000.